# IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1 Push Notification behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing application for IPhone in IBM Mobilefirst Platform 7.1 with Push Notification feature. I am sending the push notification based on the User ID.

Using adapter based authentiation, I am retrieving the User ID and subscribing to Push Notification based on the User ID.

The push notification behavior in my app:

> 1. Login and subscribe to push notification
> 2. Logout
> 3. Send Notification [ When app is in foreground ] - Successfully received and processed
> 4. Send Notification [ When app is in background ] - Successfully received and processed
> 5. Send Notification [ After killing the app running in background ] - Successfully received but can able to receive the notification content
>      and process it only after login ( i.e. pushNotificationInvoked
>      function is triggered with payload only after login)

Now, the point is, when the app is in foreground and background we can able to receive and process the notification regardless of the user is logged in or not. Then why do you need to login, on click of received notification when app is not running in foreground or background.

Is this the way MFP is handling the notification? or is there anything that I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only once the user has logged-in, you can associate the notification with the user, without this you may display private data incoming with the notification to users who shouldn't receive it, since multiple users can potentially use the device.

Comment: Any idea why the pushNotificationInvoked function is triggering only after login?